# python: pickling c objects

Tags: python, pickle

First off I'm not expecting a solution, just hoping for some pointers on how to start.

I've got a C program with an embedded Python interpreter.  The Python scripts the program uses as input obviously refer to the C-defined objects and functions.  I'd now like to make some of these objects pickleable.

The pickle docs describe how extension types can be made picklable using `__reduce__`.  But this is a Python method - how would I define this in the underlying PyObject?

Fairly sure I'm mis-understanding something...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `pickle` module comes in both a python-only and a C variant (called `cPickle`). As such, the `__reduce__` method needs to be callable from Python code.

Thus, you need to provide a `__reduce__` entry in your C object [`PyMethodDef` struct](http://docs.python.org/c-api/structures.html#PyMethodDef) with a suitable implementation.

Alternatively, you can also register a pickling function with the [`copy_reg` module](http://docs.python.org/library/copy_reg.html). This module's original usecase was to support extension modules better; the [source code](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/53fa224b95f4/Lib/copy_reg.py) for the module states:

> This is only useful to add pickle support for extension types defined in C, not for instances of user-defined classes.

Comment: Ah ha, thank you that sheds some light!So assuming I've got a C object "MyObj" which already has a `static PyMethodDef MyObj []` struct, if I add an entry `"__reduce__"` pointing to a C function, will this be callable from both Pickle and cPickle?

Comment: Exactly. The `cPickle` module looks up the method via `PyObject_GetAttr()`.